# linux pseudo terminal (open select read)

Tags: c++, linux, pty

I have a following scenario: Someone creates a pseudo terminal via opening /dev/ptmx. New terminal is created and named for example /dev/pts/2. Then, in my program I open /dev/pts/2 for reading. But I also open other devices for reading and use `select()` function to wait for any incoming data. The select have also some timeout specified for performing other stuff when no data arrives for too long. After successful select i read data using `read()` function and then print it on the screen.

I encountered an issue if the pseudo terminal is closed by the one who created it. In this case `select` function ends immediately indicating success as well as `read` ends indicating "no data" by returning zero. The issue imho is that neither select nor read returns error in such case. How should I handle this to detect that the terminal is no longer existing?

```
    Status processData()
    {
        fd_set readFileDescriptorSet; // defined somewhere else
        int maxFileDescriptor; // defined somewhere else
        struct timeval timeout; // defined somewhere else
      
        int ret = select(maxFileDescriptor + 1, &readFileDescriptorSet, nullptr, nullptr, &timeout);
        if (!ret) // timeout
            return Status::success();
        if (ret < 0) // error from select()
            return Status::error("select error");

        ssize_t rd;
        char buff[10];
        do {
            rd = read(interfaces.serialPort.getFileDescriptor(), buff, sizeof(buff) - 1);
            if (rd > 0) { // some data has been read
                buff[rd] = '\0';
                std::cout << buff;
            }
        } while (rd > 0);
        if (rd < 0) // error from read()
            return Status::error("read error");

        return Status::success();
    }
```

While the way I open the pseudo terminal is following:

```
    Status internalOpen(std::string fileName)
    {
        close();

        fileDescriptor = ::open(fileName.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
        if (fileDescriptor == -1)
            return Status::error("Terminal::internalOpen::open('" + fileName + "')");

        struct termios attributes;
        if (tcgetattr(fileDescriptor, &attributes))
            return Status::error("Terminal::internalOpen::tcgetattr()");

        setAttributes(attributes);

        if (tcsetattr(fileDescriptor, TCSANOW, &attributes))
            return Status::error("Terminal::internalOpen::tcsetattr()");

        return Status::success();
    }

    void setAttributes(struct termios &attributes)
    {
        cfmakeraw(&attributes);
        cfsetspeed(&attributes, Config::baudRate);
        attributes.c_iflag &= ~(IXOFF | IXANY);
        attributes.c_oflag &= ~(ONLCR);
        attributes.c_lflag &= ~(ECHOE);
        attributes.c_cflag &= ~(CSTOPB | CRTSCTS);
        attributes.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
        attributes.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
        attributes.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Is `interfaces.serialPort.getFileDescriptor()` non-blocking?

Comment: yes, non-blocking:
fileDescriptor = ::open(fileName.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `select()` returns indicating that there's something to be read, the shown code loops repeatedly trying to `read()` from the non-blocking file descriptor until it is 0:

```
    do {
        rd = read( ...
    } while (rd > 0);
```

That's certainly reasonable. Except that the closed connection results in the very first `read()` returning 0, which the shown logic cannot discriminate.

All that's really needed here is to keep track of whether anything has been read, prior `read()` returning 0. But if `read()` returned 0 right off the bat, your goose is cooked.

Additionally, there a few other improvements will make things more robust.

1. After `select()` returns, actually check if the file descriptor's bit remains set in the `readFileDescriptorSet`. The shown logic simply assumes that it is, by checking for all other possibilities. Still, this is somewhat fragile. It's easy to forget this assumption if something tangentially related gets modified (i.e., another fle descriptor gets thrown into the mix).
2. Use `poll()` instead of `select()`, and explicitly check for `POLLHUP|POLLRDHUP` in `revents`. The file descriptor closure condition is more explicitly called out, in the `poll()` interface.

Comment: What a great answer! I used the approach with poll() function and it works perfectly. Thank you!